# how to create view model factory for AndroidViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I need to pass value when the view model is created (userData), so I need to create a view model factory

here is my viewModel, I need `application` and `userData` to init this `ScoreViewModel`

```
class ScoreViewModel(application: Application, userData: UserKM) : AndroidViewModel(application) {



}
```

but now I am confused how to pass `application` when I create viewModel factory

```
class ScoreViewModelFactory(private val userData: UserKM) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ScoreViewModel::class.java)) {

            return ScoreViewModel(userData = userData,application = ?????? ) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }

}
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have something like this :

```
class Factory(val app: Application) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(NewsViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return NewsViewModel(app) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable to construct viewmodel")
        }
    }
```

In your activity or fragment you have :

```
/**
     * One way to delay creation of the viewModel until an appropriate lifecycle method is to use
     * lazy. This requires that viewModel not be referenced before onActivityCreated, which we
     * do in this Fragment.
     */
    private val viewModel: NewsViewModel by lazy {
        val activity = requireNotNull(this.activity) {
            "You can only access the viewModel after onActivityCreated()"
        }
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, NewsViewModel.Factory(activity.application))
            .get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

And here your viewModel can look like :

```
class NewsViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

For more detail you can look at : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/News-Cache/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/news/viewmodels/NewsViewModel.kt

Comment: so I pass activity application to viewModel factory and to viewModel ? is that permissible ? I mean, as far as I know, we don't make a reference from activities/fragment to viewModel

Comment: Yes that is completely fine to pass application from your Activity and Fragment. As you see I have a lazy initialization for ViewModel in a Fragment : https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/News-Cache/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/news/ui/NewsFragment.kt

Comment: i have accepted, but I have one more question, if I don't use lazy initialization, will it be a problem ? I initialize the viewModel on onActivityCreated usually

Comment: That is also fine, you do not have to lazy initialize.

Comment: Thanks Ali. I also had a tough inner argument as to whether its a good idea to pass application to the view model

Comment: Do you know how to write test case for this fragment which we have intialize the viewmodel.

Comment: @DayaNithi I know how to write test for ViewModel, Repository and UseCase layers but not fragment. Please let us know if you found a solution.